# Change font blackness

Tags: fonts, color, fontspec

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Scale=0.9]{Trebuchet MS}

\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

I'm using `XeLaTeX` but the text is way to black, it's like if I were writing the whole document by using `\textbf{}`. Is there a way to get a 'softer' font? Not too black I mean.

Comment: Try adding `Color=black!70` (70% black) to your `font` `spec`ification.

Comment: I've added it but there's no changes. I put 70, 80, 90 but text font remained still.

Comment: The "weight" or "blackness" of a font is determined by the font designer. If you feel Trebuchet MS is too black for your liking, you must change to a different font. Some fonts offer a "Light" weight in addition to "Bold" and "Regular" (and possibly others), but unfortunately Trebuchet MS is not such a font.

Answer (score 2):

Define your colour shade of black *first* and then add that to the `font` `spec`ification using the `Color` (or `Colour`) key-value:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\fontspec[Scale=0.9]{Trebuchet MS}

\lipsum[1]

\definecolor{myblack}{rgb}{.7,.7,.7}% 30% black
\addfontfeature{Color=myblack}%

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Combined usage would be

```
\definecolor{myblack}{rgb}{..,..,..}
\fontspec[Scale=0.9,Color=myblack]{Trebuchet MS}
```

Comment: Based on the mention of `\textbf` in the question I gathered the OP is asking about the font's weight, or "color" in the typographical sense, not the literal color of the text.

Comment: @PaulGessler: True... My approach provides a "poor man's weight" for the font. :-| Not ideal.